# Hiding partial content using css

Tags: css

I have the below mark-up to style. Problem I have is I only want to show partial of it.
The text within .standfirst needs to hide but text within .byline needs to show.

Is that even possible with CSS?

```
<p class="standfirst">
<span class="article-info"><em class="byline">Rory Callinan</em></span>
A FORMER nightwatchman at the Port Macquarie company accused of dumping contaminated waste.
</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way would be to refactor your HTML so you could easily select the portion you want visible.

However, it *is* possible (albeit ugly) using that markup.

```
.standfirst {
   font-size: 0;   
}

.standfirst .byline {
   font-size: 12px;   
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NUYK2/).

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it with the nesting you've shown here.  The only way to do it is to wrap what you want to hide separately in some fashion, e.g.

```
<p class="standfirst">
<span class="article-info"><em class="byline">Rory Callinan</em></span>
<span class='content'>A FORMER nightwatchman at the Port Macquarie company accused of dumping contaminated waste.</span>
</p>
```

Comment: Was hoping for a way not having to change the mark-up as it's CMS produced.

Comment: Not going to happen.  You'll have to change the markup either on the server (most CMS's offer templating options) or you could possibly hack at it with javascript on the client, but that's probably more bug-prone.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to wrap your text with something:

```
<p class="standfirst">
    <span class="article-info"><em class="byline">Rory Callinan</em></span>
    <span class="article-text">A FORMER nightwatchman at the Port Macquarie company accused of dumping contaminated waste.</span>
</p>
```

And then it's easy:

```
.article-text { display: none; }
```

Comment: Ya I know, but the problem is I can't change the mark-up. otherwise I won't be posting this question here.

Answer (score 0):

If you hide the parent element you can't display inner elements. Bets option is to change your markup to something that would work, maybe adding another span for the rest of the text and hide that.

Comment: I was hoping if there was any way around that. :(

Comment: you can surely change the markup even if it's cms produced... there are ugly, slow jquery options, but with css i think you're out of luck

Comment: unfortunately that is the constraints i have. thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this works for me in Chrome and IE6. Obviously - this isn't the best method, but if you need to get it to work than this could be an option. Be aware, elements hidden in this way still take up space on the page.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            .standfirst { visibility: hidden; }
            .standfirst .article-info { visibility: visible; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p class="standfirst">
            <span class="article-info"><em class="byline">Rory Callinan</em></span>
            A FORMER nightwatchman at the Port Macquarie company accused of dumping contaminated waste.
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```